# Is it worth to use Stereo by default for audio recording / How to check it is supported?

Tags: android, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder, android-audiorecord

I have an video recording app, by default it records audio in stereo mode:

`mediaRecorder.setAudioChannels(if (prefsManager.isAudioStereo()) 2 else 1)`

Are the many devices with more than one microphone?

How to check if stereo (2 channels) is supported?

Because from documentation of `setAudioChannels` method

> Prepare() may perform additional checks on the parameter to make sure
> whether the specified number of audio channels are applicable.

So if I set wrong count of channels it may fail to prepare recorder